# Updating dislayName in Firebase gives a syntax error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update the `displayName` with the following code. But I get an error saying cannot resolve displayName. Looks like it doesn't take {displayName:'test name', photoURL:'url to photo'} as a parameter. I am following the Firebase example and examples I found elsewhere, but can't get it to work. Thank you for your help.

```
currentUser.updateProfile({displayName:"test name",photoURL:"url to photo"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseUser's [updateProfile(UserProfileChangeRequest request)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updateProfile(com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest)) method, takes as an argument an object of type UserProfileChangeRequest. So there is no way you can pass two String objects to that method. To solve this, you should construct that object by calling UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder's [setDisplayName(String displayName)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder#setDisplayName(java.lang.String)) and [setPhotoUri(Uri photoUri)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder#setPhotoUri(android.net.Uri)) methods along with [build()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder#build()), a method that returns the exact object that you are looking for. In code it should look like this:

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("test name")
    .setPhotoUri("url to photo")
    .build();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
firebaseUser.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("displayName: ", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will the new name:

```
test name
```