# Firestore user.getUsername() return null value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my app I made an authentification systeme using firebase. I didn't use the default page of firebase but made a custom one with email and password after a click on a button :

```java
mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(lEmail, lPassowrd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                userManager.createUser();  //CREER USER DANS DATABASE FIRESTORE (PAREIL POUR EMAIL)

                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Account created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }});
```

I added a line to create the user in FireStore, and later in the code I'm using FireStore data to update his username and picture. This leads to a crash as the username is null.

When I check on the Firestore database, a user is created with an id, but the profile picture and username are null. Any idea why? When I just use the information from the FireBase auth the user has an id and a username (no picture but that's ok).

This is the function creating the user on FireStore, previously called :

```java
public void createUser() {
    FirebaseUser user = getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        String urlPicture = (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) ? user.getPhotoUrl().toString() : null;
        String username = user.getDisplayName();

        //QUAND ON CREER UN DOCUMENT SUR FIRESTORE IL A AUTO UN ID UNIQUE
        //MAIS DANS NOTRE CAS L'USER A UN ID LORSQUON L'A CREER AVEC L'AUTHENTIFICATION
        String uid = user.getUid();

        User userToCreate = new User(uid, username, urlPicture);

        Task<DocumentSnapshot> userData = getUserData();
        // If the user already exist in Firestore, we get his data (isMentor)
        userData.addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
            //if (documentSnapshot.contains(IS_MENTOR_FIELD)){
                //userToCreate.setIsMentor((Boolean) documentSnapshot.get(IS_MENTOR_FIELD));
            //}
            this.getUsersCollection().document(uid).set(userToCreate);
        });
    }
}
```

A solution would be very appreciated as I'm stuck on this for a while now

EDIT :

I tried modifying the displayName like that :

```
mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(lEmail, lPassowrd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {



                FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();

                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(lUsername).build();
                //user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("filds", "User profile updated.");
                                }
                            }
                        });

                userManager.createUser();  //CREER USER DANS DATABASE FIRESTORE (PAREIL POUR EMAIL)


                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Account created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }});
```

The logcat shows "User profile updated." but the username is still null in FireStore :/

Comment: I can see that you're using the displayName as username, but you're not updating the displayName. You need to do that in the successListener and only call createUser() once that's done

Comment: I tried that and EDIT my post to show the modification, still not working if you have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I check on the Firestore database, a user is created with an id, but the profile picture and username are null. Any idea why?

When you authenticate your users using email and password, it means that a new instance of type [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) is created. Since you are only getting the email address and the password from the user, the only field of the class that is populated is the "email". Since there is no user name involved, nor a profile picture, when you are using [getDisplayName()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getDisplayName()) or [getPhotoUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getPhotoUrl()) the result that you get is null, hence that result. If you want to populate those fields too, then you should consider either getting that information from the user, or use of one of the [available providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start). It can be Google, Facebook, or any other provider. In this way, you'll have both the user name and the profile picture URL populated.

Comment: I added a field "username" that the user fill before signIn. But I can't use this string to modify the user.displayName (which is automatically created by firebase I guess?). The user input email, apssword and username but I can't modify the displayName of the user........  it driving me nuts I can't even check the variable in a debug idk why my Log.d never appear in the stupid logcat...................

Comment: In that case, you should [update the FirebaseUser object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302328/updating-dislayname-in-firebase-gives-a-syntax-error). Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I already try that, tell me what you think of the modification I did, I copy the code in the main post in EDIT

Comment: Yes, looks good. Is `Log.d("filds", "User profile updated.");` triggered? If yes, be sure to **move** `userManager.createUser();` inside the second "onComplete", because Firebase API is asynchronous, right? Does it work now?

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work :) You're very welcome, Tritize.