# Tried to add a new field of data to Firebase user when registering, but no update X method in FirebaseUser.class file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using the Realtime database, so the users are store in the database. I am attempting to implement a 'currentLocation' field for the FirebaseUser objects so that I can eventually create a list for each user of nearby users. I was already using a HashMap to input the data, so I just added hashmap.put('currentLocation', ''); to create an empty current location field that can be updated later.

Unfortunately though I cannot find a way to set/update the currentLocation field as there is no updateCurrentLocation() method in the FirebaseUser.class. How do I add this method to this read-only file? Is this even the best way to do this?

Code:

```
    //Dashboard.java
usedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            // Logic to handle location object
                            //get current user
                            final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                            //Updates the firebase db user with their current location.
                            fUser.updateCurrentLocation(location);
                            
                            //This method is not in the firebaseuser.class file but needs to be!
                            //fUser.updateCurrentLocation(location);
                        }
                    }
                });
                
    //RegisterActivity.java

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, dismiss dialog and start register activity
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //Get user email and uid from auth
                            String email = user.getEmail();
                            String uid = user.getUid();
                            //When user is registered store user info in firebase realtime database too
                            //using HashMap
                            HashMap<Object, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            //put info in hasmap
                            hashMap.put("email", email);
                            hashMap.put("uid", uid);
                            hashMap.put("name", ""); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
      
                            hashMap.put("currentLocation", "");
                            hashMap.put("onlineStatus", "online"); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                            hashMap.put("typingTo", "noOne"); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                            hashMap.put("phone", ""); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                            hashMap.put("image", ""); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                            hashMap.put("cover", ""); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)

                            //firebase database instance
                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            //path to store user data named "Users"
                            DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Users");
                            //put data within hashmap in database
                            reference.child(uid).setValue(hashMap);

                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered...\n"+user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        
//FirebaseUser.class Bytecode

@NonNull
public Task<Void> updateEmail(@NonNull String email) {
    Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(email);
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance(this.zza()).zzn(this, email);
}

@NonNull
public Task<Void> updatePassword(@NonNull String password) {
    Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(password);
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance(this.zza()).zzo(this, password);
}

@NonNull
public Task<Void> updatePhoneNumber(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance(this.zza()).zzp(this, credential);
}

@NonNull
public Task<Void> updateProfile(@NonNull UserProfileChangeRequest request) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(request);
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance(this.zza()).zzq(this, request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class, has only a few fields that are related to the authentication. If you need more details about your users, you should create a POJO class to store additional data.

This data can be stored either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) so it can be later used.

Please also note, the Realtime Database doesn't store null values. Firestore does.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I had already used this method for different values when testing and it worked. So I added like another field and set it to null and it appeared in the realtime database with a null value. I then added a form to update the value and it worked correctly.  Although it still didn't have a FirebaseUser.update()  method. So what do I need to look up to do this using a POJO? Thanks.

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseauthapp) can help you get the idea. If you need to update the FirebaseUser object, then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302328/updating-dislayname-in-firebase-gives-a-syntax-error) out.

Answer (score 0):

To update the location of the current user, you can do:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Users");
reference.child(uid).child("currentLocation").setValue("the location");
```

---

Since you mention wanting to find nearby users, I recommend checking out: [Query for nearby locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357990/query-for-nearby-locations) and https://github.com/firebase/geofire-android/